# Linux EDI file format validator

Tags: edi

I am searching for a Linux open source EDI file format validator. I have searched a lot but I couldn't able to find an open source tool which works in linux.

Is there any such open source tool available for linux to do at least basic EDI file format validation?

Comment: Are you trying to parse X12 or EDIFACT?  You can look at BOTS (http://bots.sourceforge.net/en/index.shtml) but that's more of a translator than a validation engine.

Answer (score 0):

as Andrew say, bots does this.
bots is also used as online validator:
send an email with the edifact file as attachment to easydesadv@gmail.com
A email report will be send back within a  minute.
Mind: edifact only, use complete interchanges (incl UNB/UNZ).

Comment: Always glad to send people your way.  The question leaves a lot to assume / guess at though.  Do you charge for this service?

Comment: no, the service is free. It checks the edifact UN message definitions. Biggest problems seems to be that people send word-documents, excel files, inhouse files etc.